# How to use standard in

Tags: python, csv

This program takes in a command line argument like `./script.py 2,3 simple.CSV`

with simple.CSV containing

```
A,B,C,D
A,E,F,G
Z,E,C,D
Z,W,C,Q
```

and outputs

```
3   C
2   E
1   B
1   F
1   W
```

As you can see, the program counts the strings in columns 2 and 3 then prints their count in descending order. However, I need to be able to call something like `./script.py 2,3` and it read from standard in. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated on the easiest way to do this.

Here is my current code as well.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
import sys
import collections

i = 2
l = 0
argc = len(sys.argv)

wordcount = {}
fieldsList = []
fieldsList = sys.argv[1].split(',')

while l < len(fieldsList):
    fieldsList[l] = int(fieldsList[l])
    fieldsList[l] = fieldsList[l]-1
    l += 1

while i < argc:
    with open(sys.argv[i], newline='') as csvfile:
        for line in csvfile.readlines():
            colLen = line.split(',')

        numColumns = len(colLen)
        csvfile.seek(0)

        csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        next(csvReader)

        for row in csvReader:
            for a in fieldsList:
                content = row[a]
                if content not in wordcount:
                    wordcount[content] = 1
                else:
                    wordcount[content] += 1

i += 1

wordCounter = collections.Counter(wordcount)
for word, count in wordCounter.most_common():
    print(count, " ", word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply passing it as the first argument, as in `csv.reader(sys.stdin, ...)`, will do the trick.

Note that you can't seek in stdin, because it's a stream, not a file. But you don't need to, because it's only used to count the columns and `numColumns` is unused anyway. (If you needed it, `csv.reader` can tell you too.)

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./count-field-values-stdin.py", line 24, in <module>
    with open(sys.stdin, newline='') as csvfile:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper' this is the error I get when attempting that

Comment: I have figured out how to read from stdin, any ideas on how to skip the header line of the CSV file when it is piped from a cat command?

Comment: `open(sys.stdin, newline='') as csvfile` is not the code from my answer. You don't need to open stdin, it's already open.

Comment: Simply do `next(csvReader)` to skip a line.